# What are different types of serve strategies in squash?

Tags: serve, squash

I am quite new to playing squash.
As I watch professional matches on YouTube,
I notice quite a few different types of serves.
As the title states,
what are the different types of serve strategies in squash?

Answer (score 6):

Serve strategies are used to gain advantage over an opponent. A lob will hit the front wall high and central, and will take the ball over head to the back of the opponents half.

If a player returns this type of serve easily then a change of serve tactic may be used. Eg, A smash or power serve.  This is when the server serves the ball with a powerful smashing action. It is aimed to hit just above the service line at center or off center.  The ball will come very fast and lower down at a steeper angle. Depending where it strikes the wall, it may come directly at the opponent or to their left.

Another type is to hit front wall at an angle, causing the ball to then deflect off the side wall towards the opponent. This forces the opponent to change or alter stance to return the serve, giving a possible advantage.

There are other variations, but it is always a good idea to vary your serves so as not to become predictable.